# ng-model is not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on MEAN Stack web application. I am trying to use 2D array in one of my model. Here is schema of specific field:

```
alerts:  [{ name: String, time: Number}]
```

Now I am trying to access it in my UI application. Here is my approach to access data.

**code in controller:**

```
 $scope.getalerts = function(){
          console.log("Getting Alerts Tasks...!");

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.task.alerts.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.task.alerts[i].name == "NewUserAssigned") {
                            $scope.task.NewUserAssigned = true;
                            $scope.task.NewUserAssignedtime = $scope.task.alerts[i].time;
                        }
                    else if ($scope.task.alerts[i].name == "EditedDeleted") {
                            $scope.task.EditedDeleted = true;
                            $scope.task.EditedDeletedtime = $scope.task.alerts[i].time;
                        }

                }
```

**code in view:**

```
                        <uib-tab index="4" heading="Alerts" class="nav nav-tabs">

                        <div id="task_alerts" class="tab-pane">

                            <div class="alert_block">
                              <div class="task_checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-custom" id="assign_task_new_user" ng-model="task.NewUserAssigned" ng-checked="task.NewUserAssigned == true" alerts-block>
                                <label for="assign_task_new_user"  class="checkbox-custom-label">When a New User Assigned</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="alert_reminder col-lg-5" ng-if="task.NewUserAssigned == true">
                                <select class="alert_reminder_dd" ng-model="task.NewUserAssignedtime" >
                                  <option value="1">1 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="2">2 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="3">3 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="4">4 Day Prior</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="dd_caret"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="alert_block">
                              <div class="task_checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-custom" id="edit_delete_task" ng-model="task.EditedDeleted" ng-checked="task.EditedDeleted == true" alerts-block>
                                <label for="edit_delete_task" class="checkbox-custom-label">Task is Edited / Deleted</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="alert_reminder col-lg-5" ng-if="task.EditedDeleted == true">
                                <select class="alert_reminder_dd" ng-model="task.EditedDeletedtime">
                                  <option value="1">1 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="2">2 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="3">3 Day Prior</option>
                                  <option value="4">4 Day Prior</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="dd_caret"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>   

                    </uib-tab>
```

It saves data correctly if I debug it console. But when it access data from db, what does it do is that it checks options correctly but doesn't update value in **time model**. Second thing is that it doesn't show array values on console (after getting values from database).

Answer (score 0):

use ng-options instead of ng-repeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions